# Software Center not Opening at all Error

Tags: 14.04, software-center, dpkg

When I open software from menu, it says "cannot open software database. Please reinstall the software-center package.
When I write software-center on terminal, such error comes:

```
2014-05-28 09:11:20,584 - softwarecenter.ui.gtk3.app - INFO - setting up proxy 'None'
2014-05-28 09:11:20,593 - softwarecenter.ui.gtk3.app - ERROR - xapian open failed
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/app.py", line 302, in __init__
if self.db.schema_version() != DB_SCHEMA_VERSION:
File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/db/database.py", line 289, in schema_version
return self.xapiandb.get_metadata("db-schema-version")
File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/db/database.py", line 177, in xapiandb
self._db_per_thread[thread_name] = self._get_new_xapiandb()
File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/db/database.py", line 190, in _get_new_xapiandb
xapiandb = xapian.Database(self._db_pathname)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/xapian/__init__.py", line 3667, in __init__
_xapian.Database_swiginit(self,_xapian.new_Database(*args))
DatabaseCorruptError: /var/cache/software-center/xapian/iamchert: Chert version file should be 28 bytes, actually 0
```

Now, when I write command `sudo apt-get remove software-center`

```
dpkg: error: corrupt info database format file '/var/lib/dpkg/info/format'
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)
```

I had ubuntu before but it kind of got corrupted. Now, I have freshly reinstalled it and even at start, software center is not opening and this error comes. 
I hope you have a solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The cache files are corrupted. To regenerate it open a terminal and enter the following:

```
sudo rm -r /var/cache/software-center/xapian
sudo mv /var/lib/dpkg/info/format /var/lib/dpkg/info/format.bak
sudo dpkg --clear-avail
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install --reinstall software-center
```

Answer (score 2):

Press  <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> simultaneously to enter terminal.

**To uninstall Software Center:**

1. `sudo apt-get remove software-center`
2. `sudo apt-get autoremove software-center`

**To re-install Software Center:**

1. `sudo apt-get update`
2. `sudo apt-get install software-center -y`

Comment: I mentioned the error faced when i try to uninstall software center in the question posted

Comment: Try to re-install it, what does it then?

Comment: software-center is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 36 not upgraded.

Comment: Does `sudo apt-get autoremove software-center` work?

Comment: No, it gives the same error

Comment: What if you enter this in a Terminal: `software center`

Comment: Usually with autoremove you do not specify a package.  Simply sudo apt-get autoremove will do the trick.