# can not open software center 14.04 LTS

Tags: 14.04, package-management, software-center

OS - Ubuntu 14.04 lts

Background - wanted to install chrome, but software centre was not opening.

What I did -

1. tried to uninstall and re-install software centre through terminal. failed. result -

[image]

2. opened package manager it says -

[image]

3. Tried this solution - [one of the solutions suggested for same question](https://askubuntu.com/a/473371/189148)

it gives this result -

[image]

Now what to do??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try (re-)downloading chrome from the official website.
Install using terminal (replace chrome.deb with the actual filename):

```
dpkg -i chrome.deb
apt-get install -f
```

Comment: failed. installation file downloaded. but can not open in Software-centre.

Comment: @sangharsh try what I've added to my answer

Comment: tried. result - dpkg-deb: error: failed to read archive `chrome.deb': No such file or directory

Comment: @sangharsh Please read my answer completely: "replace chrome.deb with the actual filename"

Comment: sorry. I missed it.

Comment: @sangharsh This may happen to anybody, including myself - But does it work?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/27040/discussion-between-sangharsh-and-bmicraft).

Answer (score 2):

Add a repository, so that the Google Chrome can be installed

```
wget -q -O - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | sudo apt-key add - 
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list'
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install google-chrome-stable
```

After that start

```
sudo apt-get install software-center
```

If you don't need Google Chrome, remove with

```
sudo apt-get purge google-chrome-stable
```

and remove the repository

```
sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list
sudo apt-get update
```

Comment: I tried all the options. Not working yet.
After working on 1st command the result is -

The following packages will be upgraded:
  google-chrome-stable
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 533 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/47.3 MB of archives.
After this operation, 186 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Selecting previously unselected package google-chrome-stable.
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)

Comment: No more messages?