# How do I uninstall steam without the software center or the terminal

Tags: 14.04, package-management, software-center, steam

The Ubuntu software centre force closes when I open it and the terminal will not install or remove anything due to an error.

The error message was:

```
Error: Opening the cache (E:Encountered a section with no Package: header, 
E:Problem with MergeList/var/lib/apt/lists/repo.steampowered.com_steam_dists_precise_steam_i18n_Translation-en,          
E:The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.) This usually means that your installed packages have unmet dependencies
```

This has kept me from installing any new software or updating Ubuntu in general. It has confused me for a while because it has stopped almost everything I try to do in my tracks.

My OS is 14.04.2 LTS 64 bit, kernel version is 3.13.0-58-generic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had a similar issue, I did this:

Open Terminal and enter the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get -f install --fix-broken 
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/* -vf
sudo apt-get update
```

Some useful info here: [LINK1](http://2buntu.com/articles/1072/terminal-is-your-friend-basic-linux-commands-part-ii-using-apt-get-and-apt-cache/) and here: [LINK2](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2015/01/fix-broken-packages-in-ubuntu/)

and this post here: [LINK3](https://askubuntu.com/questions/473345/software-center-not-opening-at-all-error)